# css and jquery not apply for dyanamically created html

Tags: jquery, jsp

I am creating HTML Dyanamically.But css and jquery not apply for that.
Below code i am writting in tab.js and i included this file in my jsp file.When i added same code in jsp.It is working fine but when i am adding same code in tab.js not working.

```
$('#tabpage_4').append("<div class='side-by-side clearfix'><em>Skills  :</em><select data-placeholder='Your Favorite Types of Bear'  multiple class='chosen-select' style='width:350px;' tabindex='18' id='multiple-label-example'><option>American Black Bear</option><option>Asiatic Black Bear</option></select></div>");
```

Comment: is your code appending correctly?????

Comment: Yes correctly i checked

Comment: appending when included in tab.js????/

Comment: i added bottom in my jsp

Comment: I solved that i called fuction after append and working fine...Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

Write your code in `$(document).ready()` like,

```
$(function(){
   $('#tabpage_4').length && $('#tabpage_4').append("your html here");
});
```

Comment: `$('#tabpage_4').length && $('#tabpage_4').append("your html here")` why? no element, no append.

Comment: Sir i added nd checked but not working...but thanx for comment

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this...

See this ***[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/65dhL/1/)***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tabpage_4').append("<div class='side-by-side clearfix'><em>Skills  :</em><select data-placeholder='Your Favorite Types of Bear'  class='chosen-select' style='width:350px;' tabindex='18' id='multiple-label-example'> <option>American Black Bear</option></option><option>Asiatic Black Bear</option></select></div>");});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `tab.js` before closing `</body>` also make sure you are calling properly.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tab.js"></script>
</body>
```

To check it add `alert("in tab.js");`